# Find Method Implementation for Multidimensional Array in C#

Tags: c#, array, .net, generics, lambda

I found that [Array.Find(T[], Predicate) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.find?view=net-8.0) is only support one dimensional array. I am trying to generalize it to multi-dimensional array in this post.

**The experimental implementation**

The experimental implementation is as below.

- Find Method Implementation

  ```
  public class Infrastructures
  {
      public static T? Find<T>(T[,] array, Predicate<T> match)
      {
          if (array is null)
          {
              throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
          }

          if (match is null)
          {
              throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(match));
          }

          for (long row = 0; row < array.GetLongLength(0); row++)
          {
              for (long column = 0; column < array.GetLongLength(1); column++)
              {
                  if (match(array[row, column]))
                  {
                      return array[row, column];
                  }
              }
          }
          return default;
      }

      public static T? Find<T>(T[,,] array, Predicate<T> match)
      {
          if (array is null)
          {
              throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
          }

          if (match is null)
          {
              throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(match));
          }

          for (long dim1 = 0; dim1 < array.GetLongLength(0); dim1++)
          {
              for (long dim2 = 0; dim2 < array.GetLongLength(1); dim2++)
              {
                  for (long dim3 = 0; dim3 < array.GetLongLength(2); dim3++)
                  {
                      if (match(array[dim1, dim2, dim3]))
                      {
                          return array[dim1, dim2, dim3];
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          return default;
      }

      public static T? Find<T>(T[,,,] array, Predicate<T> match)
      {
          if (array is null)
          {
              throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
          }

          if (match is null)
          {
              throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(match));
          }

          for (long dim1 = 0; dim1 < array.GetLongLength(0); dim1++)
          {
              for (long dim2 = 0; dim2 < array.GetLongLength(1); dim2++)
              {
                  for (long dim3 = 0; dim3 < array.GetLongLength(2); dim3++)
                  {
                      for(long dim4 = 0; dim4 < array.GetLongLength(3); dim4++)
                      {
                          if (match(array[dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4]))
                          {
                              return array[dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4];
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          return default;
      }

      public static T? Find<T>(T[,,,,] array, Predicate<T> match)
      {
          if (array is null)
          {
              throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
          }

          if (match is null)
          {
              throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(match));
          }

          for (long dim1 = 0; dim1 < array.GetLongLength(0); dim1++)
          {
              for (long dim2 = 0; dim2 < array.GetLongLength(1); dim2++)
              {
                  for (long dim3 = 0; dim3 < array.GetLongLength(2); dim3++)
                  {
                      for (long dim4 = 0; dim4 < array.GetLongLength(3); dim4++)
                      {
                          for(long dim5 = 0; dim5 < array.GetLongLength(4); dim5++)
                          {
                              if (match(array[dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4, dim5]))
                              {
                                  return array[dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4, dim5];
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          return default;
      }

      public static T? Find<T>(T[,,,,,] array, Predicate<T> match)
      {
          if (array is null)
          {
              throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
          }

          if (match is null)
          {
              throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(match));
          }

          for (long dim1 = 0; dim1 < array.GetLongLength(0); dim1++)
          {
              for (long dim2 = 0; dim2 < array.GetLongLength(1); dim2++)
              {
                  for (long dim3 = 0; dim3 < array.GetLongLength(2); dim3++)
                  {
                      for (long dim4 = 0; dim4 < array.GetLongLength(3); dim4++)
                      {
                          for (long dim5 = 0; dim5 < array.GetLongLength(4); dim5++)
                          {
                              for(long dim6 = 0; dim6 < array.GetLongLength(5); dim6++)
                              {
                                  if (match(array[dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4, dim5, dim6]))
                                  {
                                      return array[dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4, dim5, dim6];
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          return default;
      }
  }
  ```

**Test cases**

The test cases listed here include two dimensional case, three dimensional case and four dimensional case.

```
Console.WriteLine("Two dimensional find method test:");
Point[,] Points2D = { { new Point(100, 200), new Point(300, 400) }, { new Point(100, 400), new Point(200, 400) } };
var first2D = Infrastructures.Find(Points2D, x => x.X == 100);

// Display the first structure found.
Console.WriteLine("Found: X = {0}, Y = {1}", first2D.X, first2D.Y);

Console.WriteLine("Three dimensional find method test:");
Point[,,] Points3D = {  { { new Point(100, 200), new Point(300, 400) }, { new Point(100, 400), new Point(200, 400) } },
                        { { new Point(100, 200), new Point(300, 400) }, { new Point(100, 400), new Point(200, 400) } }
};
var first3D = Infrastructures.Find(Points3D, x => x.X == 100);

Console.WriteLine("Three dimensional find method test:");

// Display the first structure found.
Console.WriteLine("Found: X = {0}, Y = {1}", first3D.X, first3D.Y);

Console.WriteLine("Four dimensional find method test:");
Point[,,,] Points4D = { { { { new Point(100, 200), new Point(300, 400) }, { new Point(100, 400), new Point(200, 400) } },
                        { { new Point(100, 200), new Point(300, 400) }, { new Point(100, 400), new Point(200, 400) } }
                        },
                        { { { new Point(100, 200), new Point(300, 400) }, { new Point(100, 400), new Point(200, 400) } },
                        { { new Point(100, 200), new Point(300, 400) }, { new Point(100, 400), new Point(200, 400) } }
                        }};
var first4D = Infrastructures.Find(Points4D, x => x.X == 100);

// Display the first structure found.
Console.WriteLine("Found: X = {0}, Y = {1}", first4D.X, first4D.Y);
```

The output of the test code above:

```
Two dimensional find method test:
Found: X = 100, Y = 200
Three dimensional find method test:
Three dimensional find method test:
Found: X = 100, Y = 200
Four dimensional find method test:
Found: X = 100, Y = 200
```

I am seeking a more generalized way to perform `find` operation in multidimensional array. All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply cast the array and use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/). The approach is simple enough to be used directly, but if you prefer to implement the `Find` methods, I suggest making them [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), so that the point notation can be used. To do so, the containing class must be static and the `array` parameter must be prepended with `this`.

```cs
public static class Infrastructures
{
    public static T? Find<T>(this T[,] array, Func<T, bool> match)
        => array.Cast<T>().FirstOrDefault(match);

    public static T? Find<T>(this T[,,] array, Func<T, bool> match)
        => array.Cast<T>().FirstOrDefault(match);

    public static T? Find<T>(this T[,,,] array, Func<T, bool> match) 
        => array.Cast<T>().FirstOrDefault(match);

    public static T? Find<T>(this T[,,,,] array, Func<T, bool> match)
        => array.Cast<T>().FirstOrDefault(match);

    public static T? Find<T>(this T[,,,,,] array, Func<T, bool> match)
        => array.Cast<T>().FirstOrDefault(match);
}
```

Note that multidimensional arrays implement `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>`. The `Enumerable.Cast<T>()` extension method converts `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<T>`.

We could also add a more generic method dealing any number of array dimensions by using an `Array array` parameter; however, this is not type safe and we would have to specify the type parameter (e.g., `array.Find<int>(...)`) when calling `Find`.:

```cs
public static T? Find<T>(this Array array, Func<T, bool> match)
    => array.Cast<T>().FirstOrDefault(match);
```

This test...

```cs
int[,] t2 = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
int[,,] t3 = { { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }, { { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } } };

int result1 = t2.Find(x => x == 3);
int result2 = t3.Find(x => x == 5);

Console.WriteLine(result1);
Console.WriteLine(result2);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Prints 3 and 5.

Note also that a multidimensional array can be enumerated directly with a simple foreach-statement:

```cs
foreach (int i in t3) {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```